# How to make bower download different versions of dependency

Tags: polymer, bower, web-component, bower-install

I have something like this in my bower.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "web-component-A": "~1.0.0",
    "web-component-B": "~1.0.0"
}
```

In the case that there is a conflict that both components need different versions of some dependency (for instance **polymer**) bower will prompt a question:
*"Unable to find a suitable version for polymer, please choose one by typing one of the numbers below"*

Is there an option to download both versions automatically?

Thank you,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

Well you already have the anwser in your Question it is only posible to download it to diffent folders:

```
"dependencies": {
    "polymer": "polymer#2.0.0",
    "polymer-legacy": "polymer#1.9.0"
}
```

But it is not possible to have two diffent version under the same name:

```
//This does not work!
"dependencies": {
    "polymer": "polymer#2.0.0",
    "polymer": "polymer#1.9.1"
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I am not aware of the dependencies of web-component-A and web-component-B. I can know it only during "bower install" itself. So I can't put "polymer" and "polymer-legacy" from the beginning.

Is it possible to make Bower to put them in different folders automatically?

Comment: Nope Bower does only create two seperate folders if you tell it to do so in the first place.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe you can suggest another packaging tool? I am starting to understand that I need a combination of npm and bower :-)

Comment: Well i think the next big thing will be yarn: https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/. But yarn  is not widly spread yet but it can manage npm and bower dependencies and others.